# Showing a linear combination of matrices is nilpotent for any constants

Tags: matrices, lie-algebras

So I have three linear operators in a $3$-dimensional vector space $V$ over field $\Bbb k$ whose matrices w.r.t basis of $V$ are

$$X=
\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
-2 &1 &-1
\end{matrix}\right)$$

$$Y=
\left(\begin{matrix}1 & -1 & 0\\
1 & -1 & 0\\
-2 &2 &0
\end{matrix}\right)$$

$$Z=
\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1\\
-1 &0 &-1
\end{matrix}\right)$$

I have to show that any linear combination of these matrices (with coefficients in $\Bbb k$) is nilpotent. What kind of approach should I be taking here? Thanks

Comment: There is a problem with your statement: $X$ and $Y$ are nilpotent, but $Z$ is not (and actually $Z^5=-4Z$).

Comment: My mistake, i have corrected Z. Thanks

Comment: One easy way, though a bit cumbersome: compute the third power of matrix $\lambda X+\mu Y+\nu Z$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Or compute the characteristic polynomial of $\lambda X+\mu Y+\nu Z$, and see that it is $f(t)=t^3$. This is not cumbersome, I think.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}$This is a drastic simplification of my previous solution - should have thought of it before, as there is a sound theoretical reason for it.

Let us rewrite $X, Y, Z$ in terms of the basis
$$
e_1, e_1 + e_2 - 2 e_3, e_1 + e_2 - e_3.
$$
We have
$$
X : e_{1} \mapsto e_1 + e_2 - 2 e_3 \mapsto e_1 + e_2 - e_3 \mapsto 0
$$
$$
Y : \begin{cases}
e_1 \mapsto e_1 + e_2 - 2 e_3 \mapsto 0\\
e_1 + e_2 - e_3 \mapsto 0
\end{cases}
$$
$$
Z : \begin{cases}
e_1 \mapsto e_1 + e_2 - e_3 \mapsto 0\\
e_1 + e_2 - e_3 \mapsto 0
\end{cases}
$$

So rewriting the matrices $X', Y', Z'$ with respect to this new basis we have
$$
X' = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix},
\quad
Y' = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix},
\quad
Z' = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

So these three matrices span the space of strictly lower triangular matrices
$$
\left\{\  \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
a + b & 0 & 0\\
c & a & 0\\
\end{bmatrix} : a, b, c \in \mathbb{k}\ \right\}
=
\left\{\  \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
s & 0 & 0\\
u & t & 0\\
\end{bmatrix} : s, t, u \in \mathbb{k}\ \right\},
$$
which is well-known to consist of nilpotent matrices.

So they point is (and I should have thought of it immediately) that **the three matrices can be put simultaneously in strictly lower triangular form**.

Comment: nice work. i also did not see all the common columns in the matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Answer may be incomplete. I will revisit when I have time.

Note that this isn't a very elegant answer. Perhaps there is a better way.

Taking a cue from Jean-Claude Arbaut's comment, I've used [octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) to verify that $Y^2 = 0$ and $Z^2 = 0$.

I've also verified that $X^2 Y = 0$, $X^2 Z = 0$ and $X Y Z = 0$.

Note also that $X^3 = Y^3 = Z^3 = 0$, since the operators have to be nilpotent.

Order of the terms don't matter, since the null spaces grow regardless of the order to take up the entire 3 dimensions.

The above shows that the expansion of $(aX+bY+cZ)^3$ has to be zero, since the expansion involves all of the above terms multiplied by a matrix and/or constant.

Comment: I'm not sure that solution is complete because the matrices do not commute. (e.g. What about $a^{2}bXYX$?)

Comment: See my edit. Order doesnt matter. Null space expands to entire space regardless. Will give more argumentation later...

Comment: Hold on. You may be right.

Comment: I think you are right in general but not when you have nilpotent operators. After I check the details, I will post.

Comment: I am sure it is true by noting that the Jordan Canonical Form of any nilpotent matrix is strictly upper triangular because a nilpotent matrix only has 0 as an eigenvalue. I missed your edit at the time I made a comment, but the remark about the ordering of the matrix felt incomplete anyway. (I am not sure how I would connect the dots from the above observation, but it makes me feel like the null space growing should be true.)